# Swift - print object from array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to print out "person" from the one of the dictionaries. I'm sure it's very simple but I have not been able to find an answer for Swift 2.0

```
var dic =
["person" : "Jane",
"country" : "US"]

var dic1 =
["person" : "Bill",
"country" : "UK"]

var dic2 =
["person" : "Jin",
 "country" : "NK"]

var bigArray = [dic, dic1, dic2]
var myAnswer = bigArray[1].valueForKey("person") as! String
print(myAnswer)
```

It throws me the error, "Value of type '[String : String]' has no member "valueForKey". What am I missing here?

Comment: try to cast bigArray[1] to NSDictionary type and then do value for key.

Comment: Use subscripting for Swift dictionary. Using .valueForKey is for NSDictionary. See "Accessing and Modifying a Dictionary" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

Answer (score 3):

You should do this way:

```
var myAnswer = bigArray[1]["person"]!
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would it something simple. But do you know when you would use .valueForKey("person")?

Comment: valueForKey is NSDictionary member so you need to cast your dictionary first to use this method but I dont recommend it because NSDictionary is Objective-C type.

Comment: For a more complete distinction, `valueForKey:` allows you to query many types of NSObject for property values by key name.  Historically, `valueForKey:` was the only way to get values out of NSDictionary, but, as time went by the typical `[key]` notation was added to objective-C and `valueForKey:` is mostly unused these days.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let dic =
    ["person" : "Jane",
        "country" : "US"]

    let dic1 =
    ["person" : "Bill",
        "country" : "UK"]

    let dic2 =
    ["person" : "Jin",
        "country" : "NK"]

    let bigArray = [dic, dic1, dic2]
    let myAnswer = bigArray[1]["person"]
    print(myAnswer)
```

Comment: Did you mean `print(myAnswer)`?

Comment: @KennethBruno yes =)

Answer (score 1):

Try to define type.

```
var dic1 : NSMutableDictionary =
["person" : "Bill",
"country" : "UK"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let myAnswer = (bigArray[1] as NSDictionary).valueForKey("person"){
  print(myAnswer)
}
```